# Tight upper bound for expectation of function of a positive and bounded random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

This problem popped up in my research.

Let $X$ be a positive and bounded ($X\in (0,B) \ a.s.$)random variable with degrees of freedom $d$ and noncentrality parameter $\lambda$. My goal is to find $\mathbb{E}(e^{g(X)})$, which I am guessing to be a pretty difficult task and thus a *tight* upper bound is good enough for me. The functional form of $g$ is quite complicated but I have found that $g$ is a positive, increasing and concave function on its domain. Now it is not clear to me whether $g$ is such that $\exp\circ g$ is concave, since if it is, I could just invoke Jensen's inequality to find an upper bound. If it is the case that $\exp\circ g$ is convex, I can use a [Hoeffding kind of technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma) to find that $X=\alpha B,\ \alpha\in (0,1)$, which then can be used to find an upper bound as $\mathbb{E}(X)\cdot {e^{g(B)}}/{B}$. However, if things are not as straight forward as these cases, I am not sure what to do because evaluating the actual integral is pretty much not an option. So my question is,

> Is there any general method (maybe similar to [Hoeffding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma) or [Bennet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bennett%27s_inequality)) that can be used in a situation like the above to find a *tight* upper bound of $\mathbb{E}(e^{g(X)})$ ?

Note that my emphasis is on a tight bound. I can find an upper bound right away using the fact that $g(X)\le g(0)+Xg'(0)$, that is, using the concavity of $g$ and then using the monotonicity of $\exp$. But I am not sure if the resulting bound  qualifies as a *tight* bound. Please share ideas and possible references to attack this problem. Thanks in advance.